# How create Parse function

Tags: java, enums

I have class Errors.
I have value errorCode.
I need get string by errorCode.

example, `int number = -2;`

```
Errors.Parse(number).toString();
```

return value `#-2#The username is already in use.`

```
public enum Errors {

        UNKNOWN_ERROR(-1, "Unknown error"), 
        LOGIN_ALREADY_EXISTS(-2, "The username is already in use."),
        LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD_NOT_CORRECT (-3, "LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD_NOT_CORRECT"),
        NULL_POINTER (-4,"Null pointer exception"),
        NOT_CORRECT_DATA (-5,"NOT_CORRECT_DATA");


        private final int errorCode;
        private final String message;

        private Errors(int errorCode, String message) {
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public int getErrorCode() {
            return errorCode;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "#" + errorCode + "#" + message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to loop the values of your enum and check individually the error code of each against the given error code (num).

something like:

```
public static Errors Parse(int num) {

  for(Errors error: Errors.values() ) {
     if (error.getErrorCode() == num ) {
         return error;
     }
  }
  return null;

}
```

Comment: @simply denis, put this method inside `Errors`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map` for that inside your `Errors` enum. Use the error code to look up the `Errors` enum. Look up the value by making a call like this: `Errors.getErrorForCode(1);`

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> allErrors;

static
{
    allErrors = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    for(Errors error : values())
    {
        allErrors.put(error.getErrorCode(), error);
    }
}

public static Errors getErrorForCode(int errorCode)
{
    Errors error = allErrors.get(errorCode);

    if(error == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown error code");
    }

    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this (especially if the parse method is used frequently):

```
private static Map<Integer, Errors> errorMap = new HashMap<Integer, Errors>();

static {
 for(Errors error : Errors.values()) {
    errorMap.put(error.getErrorCode, error);
 }
}

public static String parse (int number) {
 return errorMap.get(number).toString();
}
```